# Pandas - Multi-Index Slicing/Setting With String Wildcards

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

Have looked around and really having a hard time figuring this one out.  I want
to in a single line of code slice and set multiple cells of a pandas DataFrame
to the same value.

The blue highlighted portion is what I am trying to set.

This Works to Set - but it is only a single value:

```
dframe2.ix[('virname1','int3', 'sysname1')]['Switchport_Voice_VLAN2'] = 'test'
```

Both These Work To Slice, But Not Set:

```
dframe2.iloc[dframe2.index.get_level_values(0) == 'virname1' ]['Switchport_Voice_VLAN2']


dframe2.iloc['virname1', slice(None), 'sysname1']['Switchport_Voice_VLAN2']
```

Can someone advise if there is a better way to do this?

```
>>> dframe2
                       Switchport_Voice_VLAN Switchport_Voice_VLAN2
virname1 int1 sysname1                horses                    NaN
virname2 int2 sysname2                   NaN                 horses
virname1 int2 sysname1                horses                 newval
         int3 sysname1                horses                   test
         int4 sysname1                horses                 newval
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please format your code with `control+k` or four leading spaces.

Comment: Done - thank-you for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.loc` to select rows and/or columns by label.

Use `df.iloc` to select rows and/or columns by ordinal index.

[`df.ix` is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated) as of Pandas version 0.20.0, so avoid using it to future-proof your code.

---

In this case, use `df.loc` since `'virname1'`, `'sysname1'` and
`'Switchport_Voice_VLAN2'` are all labels.

Also note that when slicing a MultiIndex, the [index must be fully lexsorted](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex):

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=0)
```

Finally, with `df.loc` you can slice both the rows and the columns at the same time:

```
df.loc[('virname1', slice(None), 'sysname1'), 'Switchport_Voice_VLAN2'] = 'test'
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    ['virname{}'.format(i) for i in [1,2,1,1,1]],
    ['int{}'.format(i) for i in [1,2,2,3,4]],
    ['sysname{}'.format(i) for i in [1,2,1,1,1]]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Switchport_Voice_VLAN':['horses',np.nan,'horses','horses','horses'], 
                   'Switchport_Voice_VLAN2':[np.nan,'horses','newval','test','newval']},
                  index=index)
df = df.sort_index(axis=0)
df.loc[('virname1', slice(None), 'sysname1'), 'Switchport_Voice_VLAN2'] = 'test'
print(df)
```

yields

```
                       Switchport_Voice_VLAN Switchport_Voice_VLAN2
virname1 int1 sysname1                horses                   test
         int2 sysname1                horses                   test
         int3 sysname1                horses                   test
         int4 sysname1                horses                   test
virname2 int2 sysname2                   NaN                 horses
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank-you!  As a temporary solution, I copied index columns so they were normal data columns, and used the same pd.loc method you did with "==" Value-checking.  But your solution lets me do it directly on the indexes, and is much more elegant.